# Redrawing the board in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to implement a game. It takes place on a 9 by 9 board and contains Walls and one Pawn and Empty blocks. Both of these are a subclass of GameObject. GameObject extends JLabel. I store the location in an array:

```
    GameObject[][] board = {
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
        {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
};
```

For every place in the array I check which GameObject has to be placed there from a String and put it there. So that means nothing will get put there(Empty), a Wall or a Pawn. To add the GameObject(extending JLabel) to my JPanel I use the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            JPanel row = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,9));
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                GameObject col = board[i][j];
                col.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                col.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD,20));
                col.setOpaque(true);
                col.setBackground(board[i][j].getColor());

                col.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                row.add(col);
                int finalI = i;
                int finalJ = j;
            }
            row.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            panel.add(row);
        }
```

Once the user requests a move the Pawn will be placed on a different spot on the board. So the current place in the array is set to Empty and the new place is set to Pawn. Then the two squares have to be redrawn. An empty JLabel has to be drawn and the new position for the Pawn has to be drawn.
This is done in the following way:

```
board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()] = new Empty(board); //Old place is now empty
board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()].setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Set the old place color to white
pawn.movePawn(rowMove, colMove); //Move the pawn internally
board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()] = pawn; //Move the pawn on the board
board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()].setBackground(Color.BLUE); //Set the color to blue
```

Unfortunately nothing happens when I call the last bit of code. The array does get changed, the internal coordinates of the Pawn change. But in the JPanel nothing happens. How do I make sure that, every time I call the move function, my JPanel gets updated to reflect the change?

Comment: Did you try calling panel.repaint()?

Comment: Changing the data in the array has nothing to do with the components added to the panel.

Comment: Oh wait, you put the pawn in the board, that doesn't affect the layout at all. Just call board[x][y].setBackgroundColor otherwise you're losing your reference to your label at that position.

Comment: I'm already doing that here right? Calling the .setBackgroundColor?
`board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()].setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Set the old place color to white
board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()].setBackground(Color.BLUE); //Set the color to blue`

Comment: Like I change the array data and afterwards I call .setBackgroundColor on the just changed spot in the array. Which is a JLabel.

Comment: "board" is an array. It is NOT your JPanel. Changing the elements in the "board" array, does not change the components added to JPanel. What you really want to do is use Icons for each JLabel. Then you can just update the Icon of each JLabel.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood you, my bad! So that means I should change `GameObject col = new GameObject(board);` into `GameObject col = board[i][j];` in the initial creation step to still have a reference. I've done this so that board[i][j] is a reference to the created GameObject, but my UI still isn't changing.

Comment: *"I misunderstood you"* You, who? Tip: Add @matt (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: I misunderstood @camickr and @ matt. They both meant the same thing. Thank you for telling me about `@`.

Comment: You seem to have it backwards. You create the board ok. Then when you want to change the colors, don't re-assign anything in your array. Do not say board[x][y] = pawn; what that does is replaces the object in the array, but not the panel.  Grab the object you want, GameObject empty = board[iold][jold]; empty.setBackground(Color.WHITE); Don't re-assign the values in the array because then they won't reflect what is in your panel.

Comment: @matt That's it, thank you very much! I still didn't comprehend what you meant in which place. But now I get it. I thought that by updating the array I'd also update the reference, but I was creating a new object there and only updating the array. It works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ill make your example a little simpler.

```
JLabel[][] labels = new JLabel[2][2];
```

Now there is a 2D array with space for JLabels.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
for(int i = 0; i<labels.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<labels[i].length; j++){
        labels[i][j] = new JLabel(i + ", " + j);
        panel.add(labels[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Now I have filled the array with JLabels *and* added those same JLabels to the panel.

```
labels[0][0].setText("XXX");
```

That changes the JLabel in my array to have the text of XXX, it is also a JLabel that I added to my JPanel, so the changes will be reflected on screen.

```
labels[0][1] = new JLabel("XXX");
```

That changes *the array* to point at a new JLabel, it does not affect the JLabel that is in the JPanel. You will see no changes on the screen.

So what you have done:

```
board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()] = new Empty(board);
board[pawn.getRow()][pawn.getCol()].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

The array has a new Empty, the Object in the panel has not been changed at all. Then you set the background color of the new Empty, but it is not displayed anywhere.